# cronjob for wordpress runs infinitely

Tags: wordpress

I have this code:

```
// set up cron job
wp_schedule_event(time(), 'hourly', 'test_event');

add_action('test_event', 'testFunction');

function testFunction()
{
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'tour',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    ));


    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        $post_id = get_the_ID();

        echo $post_id . "a<br>";
    }

}
```

And of course, I disabled the Wp cronjob `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);`.

When I go to `http://my-domain/wp/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron` in the browser (the domain is local, so can't set the real cronjob in the crontab yet with wget), it outputs post IDs multiple times, like this:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

Sometimes even more, and sometimes it causes memory error. It seems to me like the cronjob is running infinitely. I can't figure out why.

Not a WP pro, so any suggestion is appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `wp_schedule_event`, a new event is registered. You should only call that function once (events persist through multiple visits, globally), the documentation recommends [scheduling after plugin activation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event#Schedule_an_hourly_event).

*"To schedule an hourly event in a plugin, call `wp_schedule_event` on activation (otherwise you will end up with a lot of scheduled events!)"*

You'll want to use `wp_unschedule_event` to clear your current bindings, then call the function once. If it is part of your theme, use them activation and toggle your theme to something else and back.

Comment: Is there a quick way to unbind events? If I use wp_unschedule_event call, how do I check the event is totally unregistered?

Comment: I don't know, you could look at the source code to find out where they are stored. Or try a plugin like this to view active events: https://wordpress.org/plugins/cron-view/

Comment: Looking back at this, you could just use `wp_next_scheduled` in a loop. It returns false if there is no "next event' for the given hook, so just loop the "unschedule event" function until `wp_next_scheduled` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

`wp_schedule_event` registers a cron task with your WordPress installation.

So, what you're doing here, is every time you're running your cron you are telling WordPress to run your function an additional time to the last time.

If you've visited the cron page 10 times then your cron will be running 10 times per visit.

You can unschedule the event using `wp_unschedule_event` if you need to.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the way I test it? i.e. visit that url. Because I am not too sure what wp-cron.php does. Sounds like if I have a wp_schedule_event call somewhere in the code, visiting that url will  register the event one more time?

Comment: That's exactly it, it's re-registering on every load, causing lots to be run